# System tests producing intermittent failures

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Our tests are bleeding into each other in Rails 5.1, system tests only. Specifically, we get 'ActiveRecordNotFound' errors on tests run together, but not when run individually. Almost as if the Database Clean call is happening after the next test has already begun.

Gems:

```
ruby '~> 2.5.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'chromedriver-helper'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

Rails_helper:

```
Spec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :rack_test
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
    driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
  end

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

Example failure:

```
RSpec.describe 'Banana Peeling', type: :system, js: true do
  it 'peels' do
    Timecop.freeze
    banana = create(:banana)
    visit(banana_path(banana.id))
    click_on 'start_peel'
    click_on 'save'
    expect(banana.reload.start_peel).not_to be nil
    Timecop.return
  end
end

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Banana with 'id'=6257
```

Answer (score 0):

Capybara author [recommends against](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/pull/428#issuecomment-1773729) using `Timecop.freeze` and instead to use `Timecop.travel`